# Why Docker build do not have -f parameter?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Output from

```
sudo docker build --help
```

is

```
--force-rm=false     Always remove intermediate containers, even after unsuccessful builds
--no-cache=false     Do not use cache when building the image
-q, --quiet=false    Suppress the verbose output generated by the containers
--rm=true            Remove intermediate containers after a successful build
-t, --tag=""         Repository name (and optionally a tag) to be applied to the resulting image in case of success
```

There is substantially more parameters in online documentation https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/build/

for example the parameter -f to specify the filename of Dockerfile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check your docker version, and you need to upgrade it. According to docker's [changelog](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), `docker build` with `-f` parameter is implemented in [version 1.5.0](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#150-2015-02-10)

Also I did a test on my own machine with docker version 1.6.2

```
$docker --version
Docker version 1.6.2, build 7c8fca2

$docker build --help

Usage: docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build a new image from the source code at PATH

  -c, --cpu-shares=0    CPU shares (relative weight)
  --cpuset-cpus=        CPUs in which to allow execution (0-3, 0,1)
  -f, --file=           Name of the Dockerfile (Default is 'PATH/Dockerfile')
  --force-rm=false      Always remove intermediate containers
  --help=false          Print usage
  -m, --memory=         Memory limit
  --memory-swap=        Total memory (memory + swap), '-1' to disable swap
  --no-cache=false      Do not use cache when building the image
  --pull=false          Always attempt to pull a newer version of the image
  -q, --quiet=false     Suppress the verbose output generated by the containers
  --rm=true             Remove intermediate containers after a successful build
  -t, --tag=            Repository name (and optionally a tag) for the image
```

and you can see it support `-f` parameter.